# Find a permutation that minimizes the sum

Tags: permutations, algorithms

Please help me with the following problem.

Let $n$ and $m$ be positive integers (usually, $n \sim 70 \ldots 100$);

let $x$ and $y$ be known (given) two-dimensional arrays (i.e. matrices) of size $n \times m$ whose elements are zeros or ones (i.e. binary arrays);

and let $\sigma$ be a permutation of the set $\{1,2, \ldots, n \}$.

The problem is to find all permutations $\sigma^\ast$ that minimize the following sum:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \big(x_{\sigma(i),j}-y_{i,j}\big)^2 \rightarrow \min_{\sigma}.
\tag{1}
$$

For simplicity, one can first find at least one such a permutation, and then try to find all the permutations.

Of course, instead of $(a-b)^2$, in this formulation of the problem, one can take $|a-b|$ or $a \oplus b$ (since the elements of the arrays $x$ and $y$ are 0s or 1s).

The problem is that it is impossible to iterate over all $n!$ permutations with a brute-force search. I need to come up with an algorithm that will allow to solve this problem in a reasonable time.

I started with a simplified version of the problem for the case of one-dimensional binary arrays $x$ and $y$ consisting of $n$ elements:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \big(x_{\sigma(i)}-y_{i}\big)^2 \rightarrow \min_{\sigma}.
\tag{2}
$$

How to approach the solution of the problem (2), and then of the more general problem (1)?

Thank you for your help! Now I see that the problem (1) is equivalent to the problem
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m x_{\sigma(i),j}y_{i,j} \rightarrow \max_{\sigma},
\tag{3}
$$
and the problem (2) is equivalent to the problem
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i)}y_{i} \rightarrow \max_{\sigma}
\tag{4}
$$
that is really easy to solve. But what to do with the problem (3)? There one $\sigma(i)$ is present immediately in $m$ terms. And the problem does not seem to split and does not reduce to the one-dimensional case (2) or (4). Or am I missing something?

Comment: For (2), is it possible that sorting both $\{x_i\}$ and $\{y_i\}$ in increasing order results in the minimal sum? (Permuting both simultaneously is allowed because that can be mimicked by a single permutation of $\{x_i\}$.)

Answer (score 1):

Problem $(2)$ seems easy.  Let $x_0$ and $x_1$ be the number of $0$'s and $1$'s in $x$, respectively, and define $y_0$ and $y_1$ similarly.  If $x_1\geq y_1$ map $y_1$ $1$'s ffrom $x$ to $1$'s in $y$, and map the remaining elements of $x$ arbitrarily to the remaining elements of $y$.  All the $0$'s in $x$ are mapped to $0$'s in $y$, and the number of mismatched elements is $x_1-y_1$, which is minimal.

This doesn't extend to problem $(1)$ in any obvious way, though.

Comment: Thank you very much!

And what about the general two-dimensional case (1)? What ideas can be for it here?